# Umbraco Grid custom editor not persisting config to the Model

Tags: c#, angularjs, configuration, umbraco, umbraco7

I am trying to implement a custom Umbraco Grid editor for a fixed width and height image. The config in */config/grid.editors.config.js* now looks like this:

```
[
{
    "name": "Image",
    "alias": "media",
    "view": "media",
    "icon": "icon-picture"
},
... other default editors 
{
    "name": "Fixed width image",
    "alias": "fixedwidthimage",
    "view": "media",
    "icon": "icon-picture",
    "config": {
        "size": {
            "width": 170,
            "height": 300
        }
    }
}
]
```

---

With this in place (see the last grid editor: **Fixed width image**), I can select it in the grid. Everything also persists to the view.
The problem is that I cannot get to the **config** part. It always comes up empty:

```
if (Model.editor.config != null && Model.editor.config.size != null)
{
    url += "?width=" + Model.editor.config.size.width;
    url += "&height=" + Model.editor.config.size.height;

    if (Model.value.focalPoint != null)
    {
        url += "&center=" + Model.value.focalPoint.top + "," + Model.value.focalPoint.left;
        url += "&mode=crop";
    }
}
```

Model.editor is not null and shows the correct custom editor I added in the config. 
But **Model.editor.config is {}** when evaluating the dynamic expression in Visual Studio.

Additional information: I did not do anything else then add the editor in the config as depicted above to get the custom editor working in Umbraco.

Thank you guys in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I fixed it.

It just so happened that the config was added **after** I added an item with that editor to the grid.

So, in short, always create the config before editing the grid.